# Get id from php code catch by onclick method js then pass to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a table and i should make update operations with them .I get data from mysql and firstly  I should get $id of loop and pass to another page and get $id from second page and then i know how to update only I dont know how to get appropriate id to update it in second page I am newbie in php js

```
   <div class="container">
  <h2>List of books</h2>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="myFunction()">Create</button>



  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Book name</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th><th>
                <th><th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    $id = 0;
      while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
  {
  $id++;
//  Print "<tr>";  Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['name'] . "</td> ";  
 // Print "<th>Pet:</th> <td>".$info['author'] . " </td></tr>";   
 // Print "</table>"; 

      Print"<tr>";

   Print" <td>".$info['name']."</td>";
       Print "<td>".$info['author']."</td>";
      Print  "<td>".$info['category']."</td>";
            Print  "<td>".'<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick='delete_user( {$id} );'>Edit</button>'."</td>";
            Print  "<td>".'  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>'."</td>";

 Print " </tr>";


    }  ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

 <script type='text/javascript'>

function delete_user( id ){

//this script helps us to
alert("dd")
//var answer = confirm('Are you sure? +id');



}
```

not working in line

```
 Print  "<td>".'<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick='delete_user( {$id} );'>Edit</button>'."</td>";
```

Comment: @Faran Ali POST ok but how i can get id  Print  "<td>".'<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick='delete_user( {$id} );'>Edit</button>'."</td>"; is not working

Comment: function delete_user( id ){

//this script helps us to
alert('Are you sure? +id');

}

Comment: @Faran Al what is it?

Comment: Try this @Sultan 

Print  '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="delete_user('.$id.');>Edit</button></td>';

Comment: @Faran Ali I should make like this  onclick="<a href='second.php?id=$id'>edit</a>

Comment: Can Use AJAX call also and redirect in it's response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having trouble with your quotes. It looks like your attempting to reference a PHP variable from within single quotes (although maybe not since you end the single quoted string at the js function), you can't do that. You can do it from within double quotes i.e.

`"<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-info' onclick='delete_user( {$id} );'>Edit</button></td>"`

Or you can concatenate it into the string, i.e.

`"<td>".'<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="delete_user( {' . $id . '} );">Edit</button>'."</td>"`